# How to use lua command math.eval

Tags: lua

I have heard about a lua library or function `math.eval` :

http://wiki.inspired-lua.org/index.php?title=math.eval&setlang=fr

I have this error message :

> ! LuaTeX error ./Calcul.lua:11: attempt to call field 'eval' (a nil value)
>   stack traceback:
>       ./Calcul.lua:11: in function 'NbRandom'
>       [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
>   \Calculs code ...^^@-\par \directlua { NbRandom () }

when I try to use it as this :

```
Nb = math.eval("3-7+8")
```

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the top of the page you linked:

> math.eval is a math library extension.
>
> This has been introduced in TI-Nspire OS 3.0 (Changes).

That's not a core lua function. It is specific to `TI-Nspire OS 3.0+`.

That being said I'm not sure I understand why that function even exists since `loadstring` seems to allow the same sort of thing.

```
loca val=loadstring("return 3-7+8")()
```

Comment: Ok it's not a lua command. I tried `dostring("3-7+8")` and have `! LuaTeX error ./Calcul.lua:11: attempt to call global 'dostring' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
 ./Calcul.lua:11: in function 'NbRandom'
 [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\Calculs code ...^^@-\par \directlua { NbRandom () }
`. I didn't find any explacation on this command. I saw `loadstring` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, `loadstring`. I always forget that the C api has `luaL_dostring` but there's no lua function `dostring`. Try `val=loadstring("return 3-7+8")()`

Comment: I believe TI-Nspire uses a custom function to allow recognition of a much richer set of math functions available in the calculator but not available in pure Lua.

Comment: `math.eval` is indeed **not** from pure Lua. On the TI-Nspire platform, there is a "Nspire-Lua" (it's not the traditional one, some modules have been removed, like `io`, `debug`), with APIs to use Nspire-specific functions, like calling the math engine, respond to keypresses (through event handlers), etc. `math.eval` is one of the functions that TI added to the standard math library of Lua. With loadstring, as Etan said, you could do : `math.eval = function(str) return loadstring("return " .. str)() end` to have a simple equivalent.